# Getting error : 'User' object has no attribute 'user'. in django python

Tags: python, django

i am new here in `django python`, I am learning 2 table relations, primary key foreign key scenario, for that i am using existing django `user` model and create another model `userprofile`, I want to list data of user and profile, so for that i have created rest api, when i do run api `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/`, it gives me this error : `'User' object has no attribute 'user'.` here i have added my whole code, can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue ? 
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Songs(models.Model):
    # song title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    # name of artist or group/band
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.artist)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.dob, self.address, self.country, self.city, self.zip, self.photo,
                                self.user)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Songs
from .models import UserProfile

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SongsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Songs
        fields = ("title", "artist")


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'dob', 'address', 'country', 'city', 'zip', 'photo')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'user')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

views.py

```
import rest_framework.generics
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Songs
from .serializers import SongsSerializer
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import viewsets

class ListSongsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Provides a get method handler.
    """
    queryset = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongsSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): #generics.ListAPIView, generics.RetrieveAPIView
    # viewsets.ModelViewSet
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    #print(queryset.count());
    #exit()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Show your views, please.

Comment: Check the documentation - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: @Dmitry i have added my views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you need to use a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) for the `User` - `UserProfile` relation. Otherwise, one user may have multiple profiles, which is not common practice.

Now regarding the problem, the `User` model doesn't have a `user` attribute. You need to use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to get access to the reverse related object.

To fix this problem, you can refactor your code to this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_profile")

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True) # rename this field

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'user_profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Comment: getting error : 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @NikulPanchal Sorry forgot to replace foreignkey with onetoone in my answer. Check updates please.

Comment: You are genius :)